# How can I get a connection URL from an SQLAlchemy Engine instance?

Tags: sqlalchemy, connection-string

I begin a program by generating a [`URL`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html?highlight=url#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL) object and passing it to [`create_engine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html?highlight=create_engine#sqlalchemy.create_engine). In a section of code far, far away I would like to find out what this engine is connected to, i.e. the connection URL.

Is there an easy way to do this? Using [`inspect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/inspection.html?highlight=inspect#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect) I can only see how to get the driver type. I can understand if the password component of a connection string was no longer available, but I'm hoping everything else is still available.

Any ideas?

Comment: `engine.url` returns a `URL` object

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Your comment looks like you're referring to the module `sqlalchemy.engine.url`. As far as I can see, the Engine class (`sqlalchemy.engine.Engine`) has no property documented named `url`. The only thing I can see how to do is create an object when you already know the details of the connection. I'm trying to work out how to get that information **back** from an `Engine` instance.

Comment: `Engine` class has a `url` attribute (https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L1755) Looks like it's not documented

Comment: Ah ha! I hadn't thought something so useful wouldn't be documented. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) class has an attribute [`url`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/0d2d94c25bd07c60c83438cb4f15cba243626382/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L1779). Although [not documented](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html), it is not 'underscore hidden' so I would assume safe to read.

Comment: By default, the `__str__`/`__repr__` representation of `engine.url` will mask the password like `'postgresql://myuser:***@localhost/test'`. If you need the full unmasked string without the password hidden, you should use `engine.url.render_as_string(hide_password=False)` (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.render_as_string)

Answer (score 9):

This works quite well for me:

```
    log.info("* Using DB: %s" % (engine.url))
```

Comment: I do not recommend passing raw url to logs. It contains database credentials...