# SQLAlchemy: Get database name from engine

Tags: python, sql-server

After creating an SQLALchemy `engine` like this

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@dbserver:port/db_name?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server)
```

Is there a way to get `db_name` from the engine-object? I know I can parse the name from the connection string but is there a better way of doing this? I had a look at the [SQLAlchemy-API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a connection URL from an SQLAlchemy Engine instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631210/how-can-i-get-a-connection-url-from-an-sqlalchemy-engine-instance)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The engine provides the connection information, so you can access those parameters. For example, if you're in the debugger, you can do:

```
(pdb) pp dir(dbconn.engine.url)
[...
 'database',
 'drivername',
 'get_backend_name',
 'get_dialect',
 'get_driver_name',
 'host',
 'password',
 'password_original',
 'port',
 'query',
 'translate_connect_args',
 'username']
```

So the simple way to get at the database name is:

```
engine.url.database
```

Comment: For anyone else looking through wondering how they get it from a sqlalchemy session object: `session.bind` is the engine. So it's `session.bind.url.database`