# SQLAlchemy: Get the database name from connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wonder if it is possible to get the database name after a connection. I known that it is possible with the engine created by the function 'create_engine' ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554458/sqlalchemy-get-database-name-from-engine)) and I would like to have the same possibility after a connection.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://login:pass@localhost/MyDatabase')
print (engine.url.database) # print the dabase name with an engine
con = engine.connect()
```

I looked at the inspector tool, but there is no way to retrieve the database name like:

```
db_name = inspect(con.get_database_name() )
```

May be it is not possible. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, executing `select DATABASE() as name_of_current_database` should be sufficient. For SQL Server, it would be `select DB_NAME() as name_of_current_database`. I do not know of any inherently portable way of doing this that will work irrespective of the backend.